# Illustrator: How to intersect a picture with a curved line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

I am completely new to designs and illustrator. I am designing a scientific poster, so I want to create a curved line on the left of the poster where the left of the line is filled with a background and the poster is to it's left.

I got a picture with the background I want and I created a "frame" which I want to use to crop this picture on the lift and add it to my poster. How can I do that?

Please correct or rephrase the question if you can for a better readability. Thank you.

[image]

In other words, I want to use the shape on the right to crop from the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Place the shape on the pic where you want it to crop. Make sure it's in front of the image.

Step 2) Select both objects, then click "Object ->Clipping Mask -> Make" (Or cmd+7 if you want to look cool)

Step 3) Take over the planet.

Comment: Awesome. That was easy. I was trying to use the pathfinder and it was a waste of time. Thank you.

Comment: When you finish Step 3 don't forget who got you there. ;-)